# Calling variable from game object within the same script

Tags: unity-game-engine, variables, scripting

Hi I am new to Unity and C#.

I have the following line of code that doesn't show any errors, but is also not working:

```
     orbitalVelocity = GameObject.Find("Earth").GetComponent<SetInitialOrbitalVelocity>().initialVelocity + orbitalVelocity
```

I am trying to obtain the ''initialVelocity'' from the script attached to the game object "Earth" and add it to the current "OrbitalVelocity" of the object that my script will be attached to (being "moon").

Everything is being done on a single script, which is the same script attached to all objects.

Comment: add debug statements then, find earth, get the component, get the value.. etc and see what you get at each point

Comment: maybe you should rethink that logic, from what you said "Earth" also has a SetInitialOrbitalVelocity, so Earth will try to update the orbitalVelocity using itself, it looks like a circular reference there